# Android - Simulate display with cutout

Tags: developer-options

The new 'Simulate display with cutout' feature is very useful for android development for making sure an app will work on all devices, however there are some types of cutouts I would like to try for which I am not given the option.

Does anyone know how to add new cutout presets for this feature?

Comment: There is a class named [android.view.DisplayCutout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DisplayCutout) that is used to define the cutout areas. Unfortunately it seems like the only way to add a new cutout is to change it in the AOSP sources, hence you have to compile your own ROM.